# Java Web Start doesn't launch my .jar without enabling the "show console"

Tags: java, java-web-start, jnlp, jconsole

As stated in the title, my software won't launch unless the "Show console" option is selected in Java settings. I'm not sure what kind of code you'd like me to post, so please ask.

When I try to run it, the Java dialog pops up and the progress bar that loads the software completes before it closes. When the console is up, the software finally loads and displays afterwards. Without the console, nothing happens.

I've tried to run the web start on different computers, and they all had the same problem. The console doesn't print out any error messages, so I don't have anything to use for debugging the problem.

Some information about the software:
It's a JavaFX project, compiled using Oracle jdk 1.7.0_65 on OS X with Netbeans. It requires full security permission, and all jars (I use a bunch of libraries) are being signed using a key store from a trusted vendor.

**EDIT**

I tried to launch my program through console using the following command: `javaws -viewer http://www.website.com/software.jnlp`, and - without launching my software - it returned the following result to the terminal:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sun.awt.SunToolkit.getSystemEventQueueImplPP(SunToolkit.java:1003)
    at sun.awt.SunToolkit.getSystemEventQueueImplPP(SunToolkit.java:998)
    at sun.awt.SunToolkit.getSystemEventQueueImpl(SunToolkit.java:993)
    at java.awt.Toolkit.getEventQueue(Toolkit.java:1749)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(EventQueue.java:1245)
    at javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(SwingUtilities.java:1290)
    at com.oracle.deploy.update.UpdateCheck.updateStateChange(Unknown Source)
```

Could this be of any help?

Comment: Try to clean applet cache https://www.java.com/en/download/help/plugin_cache.xml then relad your applet and check for errors in console. BTW do you see any warnings about certificates or security?

Comment: I do get some warnings when I compile the third-party libs, but no, during runtime it just notifies that the software requires extra permissions. I have already tried to clear the java applet cache, but to no avail.

Comment: I think that there is some exception raises hiddenly. Did you try to increase logging level in control panel?

Comment: I selected "show console" and enabled both tracing and logging in the settings. The console didn't give me any other clues as to what might be the cause, except perhaps this: `cache: JNLPPreverifyClassLoader.initialize: FAILED: file:/.../software.jar`

Comment: What Java version do you use to run your app?

Comment: @AlexeyIvanov I was using the same runtime as from the JDK I used to compile my software. Running the software on different versions didn't have any effect.

Comment: @bvx89 What is the exact version, output of `java -version` command?

Comment: Well, I have changed my setup since then, but back then the `java -version` gave an output that reflected the version of my JDK at the time. I have also submitted an answer to this question, and the solution works regardless of version of Java Runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For others who might have this problem, this is what caused it for me:

I had a thread running in the background that would show the stage once it was done loading all the assets. This stopped the whole thing from executing, so I had to change the loading logic inside of my code instead to allow for the primary stage to use the `show`-method in the UI-thread.